# Proxy Requests Only for Specific Hosts/IPs

Tags: proxy

I have a rooted device that whose network requests I currently debug using ProxyDroid and mitmproxy by applying a global site, and listing the addresses that bypass the proxy. For one of the apps I'm trying to debug, I'd like to instead allow requests to all but one address to bypass the proxy.

Is there any tool that allows one to explicitly specify the addresses that need to be proxied?